# inline .load() php instead of from a file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I currently have .load() in use like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#php_incl").load("lazy/geo_info.php");
```

However it doesn't work with that file due to the contents of the .php file, it produces a php error. Is it possible to .load() inline php? I'd like to load the code inline instead of through an external .php file. That way the php will execute without errors and then attach to the specified div as expected.

**What I want to do is this:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#php_incl").load("<?php php code blah ?>");
```

This does not work though, it just displays the php (without errors) where .load() is within the page, it doesn't attach the executed php to #php_incl div.

Comment: Why are you expecting PHP to execute in the browser?

Comment: `load` see the same output like you when visiting this URL in your browser.

Comment: is it not a better idea to try and fix the PHP file instead?

Answer (score 0):

The .load() will cause an HTTP request (which is probably non-sense, when the data is already present within the DOM). In case you *really* need/want to execute PHP script withing a JS file, add the following line to .htaccess (the MIME-type may vary from server to server):

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .js
```

In order to make PHP variables available to JS, I'd suggest methodology like that:

```
<?php
   $data = array(1, 2, 3);
   echo 'var data='.json_encode($data).';';
?>
console.dir(data);
```

just to care: making JS files parse-able as PHP might cause a serious mess.

Comment: treating .js files as .php is kind of nasty and defeats the purpose. Then you might as well just use a .php file.

Comment: sure, that's why I offered a better way to pass variables - plus the warning. I personally prefer tidily sorted projects, simply because searching costs too much time (and the compiler won't accept anything else).